# Bit shifting confusion in C#

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I have some old code like this:

```
private int ParseByte(byte theByte)
{
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        bytes[0] = theByte;
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);

        if (bits[0])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}
```

It's long and I figured I could trim it down like this:

```
private int ParseByte(byte theByte)
{
         return theByte >> 7;
}
```

But, I'm not getting the same values as the first function. The byte either contains 00000000 or 10000000. What am I missing here? Am I using an incorrect operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, in the first function, bits[0] returns the least significant bit, but the second function is returning the most significant bit. To modify the second function to get the least significant bit:

```
private int ParseByte(byte theByte)
{
    return theByte & 00000001;
}
```

To modify the first function to return the most significant bit, you should use bits[7] -- not bits[0].

Comment: so, the hex editor I used to look at the data displayed it as 10000000. I guess it displayed the lsb first? and I got lucky with my confusion in the BitArray?

Comment: @scott2012: I can't speak for your hex editor, but that's how BitArray works -- the least-significant bit is at index 0. You can verify this with a short bit of code:

var bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 0xf0 }); // 11110000
for (int idx = 0; idx <= 7; idx++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", idx, bits[idx]);

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent function to the first snipet is:

```
return theByte & 1 == 1
```

In the second snipet you were chechink the most significative bit and in the first snipet the least significant.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return int or string? Anyway - you can use modulo:

```
return theByte % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1"
```

OK, you edited ... and want to return int

A word to your shifting operation: you would have to use << instead of >>. But this returns (when you cast to byte instead of int) 0 or 128 and not 0 or 1. So you could rewrite your second solution as:

```
return (byte)(theByte << 7) == 128 ? 1 : 0;
```

But the other answers contain really better solutions than this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first function should check for bits[7] ?

Comment: The first function gets what I want, the second one is not working.

Comment: does the following work:
    return ((int) theByte == 128) ? 1 : 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra zero in your binary numbers (you have 9 digits in each). I'm assuming that's just a typo.

Are you sure you're doing your ordering correctly? Binary is traditionally written right-to-left, not left-to-right like most other numbering systems. If the binary number you showed is property formatted (meaning that `10000000` is really the number `128` and not the number `1`) then your first code snippet shouldn't work and the second should. If you're writing it backwards (meaning `10000000` is `1`, not `128`), then you don't even need to bitshift. Just AND it with 1 (`theByte & 1`).

In fact, regardless of the approach a bitwise AND (the `&` operator) seems more appropriate. Given that your first function works and the second does not, I'm assuming you just wrote the number backwards and need to AND it with 1 as described above.

Comment: fixed the typo. I'm not writing it backward, it's a format for some binary data I'm reading. I don't know why it was done that way. I'll try & though

Answer (score 0):

According to a user on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto.aspx) the BitArray internally stores the bits into Int32s in big endian in bit order. That could cause the problem. For a solution and further info you can visit the link.

Answer (score 0):

1st The first function does not work as it tries to return a string instead of an int.

But what you might want is this:

```
    private static int ParseByte(byte theByte)
    {
        return theByte & 1;
    }
```

However you might also want this:

```
    private static string ParseByteB(byte theByte)
    {
        return (theByte & 1).ToString();
    }
```